# Is it possible to get text with line breaks via Word api?

Tags: office-js

It seems that context.document.body.text (or paragraph.text or whatever.text) always has text value without line(newline) break. The only possible way to get text with newline characters is to parse ooxml or html. Ooxml parsing is no go because for office online ooxml is computed on server side and often takes up to 3 seconds to complete. Html retrieving is slow also and takes up to 500 ms event for one page files. It weird that you can insert text that contains newline characters (/n) but cannot retrieve this text back.

So the question is : Is it possible to get text with line breaks via Word api?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A new line character is included.  If you look carefully the text retrieved, a '\r' is returned within the text, that's a new line or paragraph marker.

The line break is also included (line breaks are inserted if users do Shift+Enter).

This is an Sample literal string returned after getting the context.document.body.text property. That document has many paragraphs, I bolded te **\r** added:

*"Video provides a powerful way to help you prove your point. When you click Online Video, you can paste in the embed code for the video you want to add. You can also type a keyword to search online for the video that best fits your document.**\r**To make your document look professionally produced, Word provides header, footer, cover page, and text box designs that complement each other. For example, you can add a matching cover page, header, and sidebar. Click Insert and then choose the elements you want from the different galleries.**\r**Themes and styles also help keep your document coordinated. When you click Design and choose a new Theme, the pictures, charts, and SmartArt graphics change to match your new theme. When you apply styles, your headings change to match the new theme.**\r**Save time in Word with new buttons that show up where you need them. To change the way a picture fits in your document, click it and a button for layout options appears next to it. When you work on a table, click where you want to add a row or a column, and then click the plus sign.**\r**Reading is easier, too, in the new Reading view. You can collapse parts of the document and focus on the text you want. If you need to stop reading before you reach the end, Word remembers where you left off - even on another device.**\r**"*

Comment: That's odd. I can see '\r' as a paragraph break, but i cannot see '\n' after Shift+Enter, they are not in the string.

Comment: Ok  one quick clarification, \n and \r have exactly the same effect, they are both paragraph markers.  Now line breaks (Shift+Enter) are also included in the text. they show up as an invisible character. get the code using range.text.charCodeAt(positionOfTheInvisdibleCharacter) its should return code 11.

Comment: Still I have no luck with getting \n. Here is screenshot https://screenshot.net/537z7un . '\r' symbols are in the resulting text(gaps on 3 and 4 row), but \n are missing from the text.

Comment: I'm using beta channel (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/beta/hosted/office.js) if it changes something.

Comment: ok thanks for adding the image I see that you are in Word Online...there might be some differences...

Comment: I've checked this in Word for Mac. I've managed to get \r for paragraph breaks, but "Shift+Enter' breaks aren't present in context.document.body.text.

Comment: ok i was able to repro. What we are missing is the line break characters in Word Online and Mac. In word for Windows it works. This is a bug and i will follow up with the team on fixing it. thanks! and good catch!

Comment: btw.. can you please share your scenario? whats the goal of getting the line breaks? thanks! also, when you send a /n character on the insertion operations you get a paragraph, not a line break.

Comment: tracking internally with 1368800 and 1368798